# How to refresh your app after displaying custom html error page of no internet in flutter

Tags: html, flutter

i Used this code to display custom error page in html in my flutter app but i noticed the default error page still shows up for a second or so, i dont know if it can be removed and also i want to be able to reload my flutter app from the custom html error page if possible:

```
InAppWebViewController webViewController;
bool showErrorPage = false;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: InAppWebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://fail.page.asd',
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        webViewController = controller;
      },
      onLoadError: (
        InAppWebViewController controller,
        String url,
        int i,
        String s
      ) async {
        print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
        /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
        webViewController.loadFile(assetFilePath: "assets/error.html");
      },
      onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
          int i, String s) async {
        print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
        /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
        webViewController.loadFile(assetFilePath: "assets/error.html");
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

My custom html code with a button i want to reload the page when there is internet in my flutter app

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
         button {
              background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 15px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="center" style="text-align:center; display: block; margin-top: 300px; width: 100%;">
     <img src= "vector.png"></img>
     <h1 style= "font-size: 6vw">No Internet Connection...</h1>
    <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh</button>
   </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did was introduce 'javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true' and 'supportMultipleWindows: false' (i used false because true was giving an error about popup block) in my flutter code

```
InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
          javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
          useHybridComposition: true, supportMultipleWindows: true),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));
```

And then my html:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
         button {
              background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 15px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
            }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
          function myFunction() {
             window.open("https://www.nigeriapropertydeals.com/");
          }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="center" style="text-align:center; display: block; margin-top: 300px; width: 100%;">
     <img src= "vector.png"></img>
     <h1 style= "font-size: 6vw">No Internet Connection...</h1>
    <button onClick="myFunction()">Refresh</button>
   </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This makes it possible to refresh my flutter app from the custom html error page